# Select Value from DB Array inside check box input

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am using various check boxes with different values and than storing the vales inside DataBase as all the checkboxes values are store inside Array

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Gym" id="details_10" name="utilities[]">
<input  type="checkbox" value="Spa" id="details_11" name="utilities[]">
```

and than store in the database like: Gym, Spa.

Later I am making MySQL query inside edit form where I will be able to edit those and other parameters. For the other inputs I am using:

```
<?php if($row['data'] == 'Sample Data'){echo 'selected="selected"';}?>
```

In this case I would like to use something like the following:

```
<input  type="checkbox" value="Gym" id="details_10" name="utilities[]"<?php if($row['utilities'] == 'Gym'){echo 'checked"';}?>>
```

Any help to achieve this result will be very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used this in these cases.

```
<?php
if($row['utilities'] == 'Gym')
{
    ?>
    <input  type="checkbox" value="Gym" id="details_10" name="utilities[]" checked="checked">
    <?php
}
else
{
    ?>
    <input  type="checkbox" value="Gym" id="details_10" name="utilities[]">
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: The problem is that utilities is an array something like that: Gym, Spa, ... It is not a single value. So the problem is how to say if some of the values in this array is Gym than yes echo checked="checked"

Comment: Do a `var_dump` of your array and post here/

Comment: 2 Parqueos, Area de niños

Comment: okay I made it work like this : (strpos($row['utilities_spanish'],'Area de niños') !== false)  thanks for your help !